# what wrong with my python datatable join function?

Tags: python, datatable

The Table sales have three columns:
"a", "b", "sum_sales_c"

The Table spec have three columns:
"a", "b", "sum_c", "sum_d"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datatable as dt
from datatable import f, min, max,by,join

if __name__ == '__main__':
   sales_01 = dt.fread("sales_01.csv")
   print(sales_01)
   spec_01 = dt.fread("spec_01.csv")
   print(spec_01)
   spec_01.key = ["a","b"]
   sales_01[:, :, join(spec_01)]
   print(sales_01)
```

I just want to join tow table with the column "a" and "b", but spec table "sum_c" and "sum_d" join failed.

print sales table:

```
   |     a      b  sum_sales_c
   | int32  int32        int32
-- + -----  -----  -----------
 0 |     1      2            1
 1 |     1      3            2
 2 |     2      1            7
 3 |     2      3            5
 4 |     3      4            6
 5 |     3      5            7
 6 |     3      6            8
 7 |     4      1            9
 8 |     5      2           10
 9 |     6      1           11
```

print spec table:

```
   |     a      b  sum_c  sum_d
   | int32  int32  int32  int32
-- + -----  -----  -----  -----
 0 |     1      2    202    500
 1 |     1      3    203    501
 2 |     2      1    409   1005
 3 |     2      3    206    504
 4 |     3      4    207    505
 5 |     3      5    208    506
 6 |     3      6    209    507
 7 |     4      1    210    508
 8 |     5      2    211    509
 9 |     6      1    212    510
```

after I use spec_01.key = ["a","b"] and print join table, looks like table spec "sum_c" and "sum_d" are lost. I don't know that went wrong.

print join table.

```
   |     a      b  sum_sales_c
   | int32  int32        int32
-- + -----  -----  -----------
 0 |     1      2            1
 1 |     1      3            2
 2 |     2      1            7
 3 |     2      3            5
 4 |     3      4            6
 5 |     3      5            7
 6 |     3      6            8
 7 |     4      1            9
 8 |     5      2           10
 9 |     6      1           11
```

My expectation is that "a","b","sum_sales_c","sum_c","sum_d".
how to modify my python code?

Comment: add files sales_01.csv and spec_01.csv to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the implementation, the `join` line actually isn't in-place but instead returns a new datatable Frame (cf [`join` test](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/blob/dc6e5b16ac6cbaf7c1ca5439d8733a1261a9ddff/tests/test-join.py#L38) for instance). Therefore, you need to collect the result and not print directly `sales_01` at the end:

```py
join_res = sales_01[:, :, join(spec_01)]
print(join_res)
```